# When should one represent oneself in court?

Tags: civil-procedure

I recognise these adages: ["a *pro se* defense is usually a bad defense."](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/06/if_john_edwards_were_to_represent_himself_would_he_have_a_fool_for_a_client.html) and ["A man who is his own lawyer has a fool for his client"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/121264/50720).

However, some *pro se* defenses have succeeded, such as the following. So when ought one to flout this adage?

1. [UKSC Justice Lord Sumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Sumption#Legal_career)  (Caveat: He is a barrister)

2. Some other notable victories [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_se_legal_representation_in_the_United_States#Notable_pro_se_litigants)